# How to make only part of a string uppercase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have strings which are incomplete URLs, like the following:

```
"dl_image/cm1111.jpg"
"dl_image/CM2222.jpg"
```

The problem is, the second is correct, the first is not. The letters between the numbers and 'dl_image/' must always be uppercase.

I am using joinging these incomplete urls onto a base url using urljoin with the following code:

```
imagehtml = temp1['dl_image']
if temp1.get('set') != None:
    if imagehtml != None and imagehtml !='':
        soup = Soup(imagehtml, 'html.parser')
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            print(urljoin(base_url, a['href']))
```

imagehtml contains the incomplete urls.

Is there a way to convert only these letters to uppercase, and not the extension or directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you like

```
url = 'dl_image/cm1111.jpg'

path, file = url.rsplit('/', 1)
name, ext = file.rsplit('.', 1)
print(path + '/' + name.upper() + '.' + ext)
```

I.e. split only at the rightmost '/' and '.' to then uppercase only the portion in between these two positions.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `str.join` with list comprehension as parameter, doing conditions and doing expected stuff:

```
>>> s="dl_image/cm1111.jpg"
>>> ''.join([v.upper() if s[i-1]=='/' or s[i-2]=='/' else v for i,v in enumerate(s)])
'dl_image/CM1111.jpg'
>>>
```

**Update:**

```
imagehtml = temp1['dl_image']
if temp1.get('set') != None:
    if imagehtml != None and imagehtml !='':
        soup = Soup(imagehtml, 'html.parser')
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            print(urljoin(base_url, ''.join([v.upper() if a['href'][i-1]=='/' or a['href'][i-2]=='/' else v for i,v in enumerate(a['href'])])))
```

Comment: I edited my question to show I am using urljoin. I guess the correct way would be to assign a["href"] to another variable, say s, then use the code you have provided and assign that to another variable, then use t in place of a["href"] as a paramter to urljoin?

Comment: @JakeRankin Now? does it work?, please accept if it works :-), and upvote :-)

Comment: @JakeRankin YW :-), happy for my help, :-), 

Comment: Big help and quickly too. Amazing :)

Comment: Actually my friend I have one more favor to ask, would it be possible to make it so that everything before .jpg is uppercase also? Just ran into a filename like CM5555ch.jpg which needs to be CM5555CH.jpg, really annoying people didn't put in this data correctly.

Comment: @JakeRankin Sure, do: `s.upper().replace('.JPG','.jpg')`, sorry for being late :-)

Comment: Lol, are you both serious? @U9-Forward, you present a solution which by design changes the first two letters right of a slash to uppercase only. And as an update for the general case (but iiuc still _file_ name only should be changed) you suggest to just dumb `upper()` the whole string and simply patch the extension back to lower - _with a hard coded `'.jpg'` in it_???? And you @Jake accept that? What's the abbreviation for rolling down the floor because of laughing...?

Comment: @SpghttCd no need to be mean. This is all quite new to me and I didn't fully understand the solution, but didn't understand that the result worked. I was unsure of the update given as a solution and was planning to ask about that.

Comment: Dear both @JakeRankin and U9-Forward, sorry if I made the impression of being mean. I was just writing what I felt, completely without any anger, _really_ just laughing from my heart. You know: Several people try to dissect a string in order to solely uppercase a very certain portion, generalized so that whatever url could go into their algorithm... - and then the accepted solution is to just - _bam_ - uppercase the whole thing and replace "JPG" by "jpg". You have to admit that this is funny. No? C'mon, just a little bit... :-)

Answer (score 2):

I personally would recommend using `str.rfind()` because the pattern in your cases will typically involve a `.` near the very end as your file extension and a `/` before the very end as your beginning of the conversion you are trying to do to your filename string. See the code below:

```
s="dl_image/cm2222.jpg"
start = s.rfind('/')
end = s.rfind('.')
new_s = s[:start] + s[start:end].upper() + s[end:]
print (new_s) 
#dl_image/CM2222.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's easy. Here's a way to do it:

1. Find index of the last `/`.
2. Find index of the place from where the extension starts.
3. Convert everything between the two indexes to upper case.

Here's a way you can translate it into code:

```
test_url = "dl_image/cm1111.jpg"
last_slash_index = test_url.rfind('/')
extension_start_index = test_url.rfind('.')
final_url = test_url[:last_slash_index+1] + test_url[last_slash_index+1:extension_start_index].upper() + test_url[extension_start_index:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
import re
a = 'dl_image/cm12345/cm12.jpg'
b = len(a)-1-a[::-1].index('/')
c = a[b:]
d = re.findall(r"\d+",c)
if len(d)>0:
  e = a.index(d[0], b)
  f = a[:b+1]+a[b+1:e].upper()+a[e:]
  print(f)
```

Output:

```
dl_image/cm12345/CM12.jpg
```